# Graph is not rendering on data change dynamically in igDataChart of igniteUI

Tags: jquery, ajax, ignite-ui, igdatachart

I have the application which is receiving data on making ajax request,
with first set of data the graph is plotting, when Ireceive the second set of data Iam calling the same igDataChart() with latest data, though the control is coming to graph plotting method the corresponding data is not renedering

Please do help me

PleaseNote:sss
There is no issue with receiving the data and also the kind of data, only issue is on **change of dataSource/data** graph is not **updating**

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the `renderSeries` method after assigning the new data. Also make sure you are assigning the new data as follows:

```
$(".selector").igDataChart("option", "dataSource", data);
$(".selector").igDataChart("renderSeries", "xAxis", true);
```